# Is there a good syslog viewer for mac?

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, logs, console

I have many devices from which I want to get logs using a syslog server hosted on my iMac.

To get in touch with logs and analyse them, I am looking for a good syslog viewer for mac which have the following functionalities :

- color log by level
- stats & graphs
- send mail and alert

I tried the common logs viewers (console, SU => https://superuser.com/questions/320575/mac-os-x-logfile-viewer) but the two last functionalities I look for are not supported by them. It exists loggly.com but only on cloud version and logmx but which exist only in free version without stats.

Has someone any idea of a good syslog viewer (opensource / free if possible) which had these functions for mac ?

Comment: have you tried the programs mentioned in here https://superuser.com/questions/320575/mac-os-x-logfile-viewer

Comment: @enzo Would you make an answer on the linked question with a link to SU? That would help many people - cheers and thank you! If you don't want to answer, propose an edit to the top voted link to show both the SU/SF links...

Comment: @bmike noted, I just assumed that he already tried some of those programs

Comment: @bmike: For sure I have tried some of them. I don't find one which have stat & graph and which send mail and alert. So I still look for a better log viewer...

Comment: @AlexisG Excellent - just edit the post to 1) explain you are aware of general solutions 2) detail precisely what your requirements are - a picture would help greatly. Then the post can be reviewed to re-open it if the people doing the voting to reopen think it's distinct enough to merit stand alone answers other than the general case. Also http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2180/how-should-i-ask-about-getting-a-software-recommendation? might help to differentiate your question from the other.

Answer (score 2):

At last, one developer is making both tools you seek.

Howard Oakley has beta versions of his programs at https://eclecticlight.co/downloads/ and blogs regularly about how to use these and explore the new log archive formats on macOS / iOS / tvOS / watchOS

His [downloads page](https://eclecticlight.co/downloads/) has two apps of interest (use the left downloads link as the product versions below are beta and may not be current in a day or week):

- [Consolation](https://eclecticlightdotcom.files.wordpress.com/2017/11/consolation3b10.zip) - an alternative console browser
- [Woodpile](https://eclecticlightdotcom.files.wordpress.com/2017/11/woodpile10b5.zip) - a tool to count / bin / analyze patterns of logging

If you picked one blog post of his to look at regarding logging, I would start here:

- https://eclecticlight.co/2017/11/22/the-unified-log-in-high-sierra-10-13-1/