# Month 13 is out of bounds?

Tags: high-sierra, error

Recently my Mac is showing up some weird messages such as "Month 13 is out of bounds".

[image]

How do I fix this error I can't go to ant apple authorized repair centre because it is very far away from an Apple centre

Comment: From @tgray: "I started getting the high CPU usage today because of UserEventAgent. It also uses a huge amount of RAM (30+ GB if I let it run long enough). Force quitting and rebooting changed nothing. I did a sample of the process and saw a ton of lines dealing with dates. When I changed the date to November my CPU usage went back to normal. The second I changed it to the present it went bonkers again.

I wonder if this is related to the iOS date bug in 11.2.1? I hope Apple fixes it soon because my computer is unusable."

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This error is logged on iOS 11 and on macOS 10.13 for sure and I'm not seeing it cause any specific function or problem on any platform.

I'll link to the main question here about "does macOS log too much" since that's an opinion and impression that is worthy of discussion. Some people might feel better if there were no messages unless a really serious condition needs action. Others want even more detail so they can know what's happening / learn / measure. So, it's going to be a tradeoff how these are issues / categorized / used.

- [Fresh macOS install: Console.app displays errors/faults. Is that to be expected?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/301836/fresh-macos-install-console-app-displays-errors-faults-is-that-to-be-expected)

One interesting developer that has some tools is Howard Oakley who blogs at https://eclecticlight.co/

His [downloads page](https://eclecticlight.co/downloads/) has two apps of interest (use the left downloads link as the product versions below are beta and may not be current in a day or week):

- [Consolation](https://eclecticlightdotcom.files.wordpress.com/2017/11/consolation3b10.zip) - an alternative console browser
- [Woodpile](https://eclecticlightdotcom.files.wordpress.com/2017/11/woodpile10b5.zip) - a tool to count / bin / analyze patterns of logging

Answer (score 10):

I can verify the legitimacy of this problem. I had the same issue yesterday, and after a restart, the computer was rendered almost useless due to this error. For some reason, the computer can't deal with this month and throws errors wherever there are databases or plists.

To fix this:

1. Open Activity Monitor and force quit two processes: `lsd`, `UserEventAgent`
2. Open System Preferences and navigate to "Date & Time"
3. Uncheck "Set date and time automatically"
4. In the calendar, select a date prior to December 2017 and press Save
5. If `UserEventAgent` or `lsd` continue to cause problems, then force quit them again after setting the date.

[Other people here have this problem](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/88417)

Why?

It seems to me, UserEventAgent was attempting to use two plist files:

```
System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.UserEventAgent-Aqua.plist
```

and

```
System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.UserEventAgent-LoginWindow.plist
```

When it tried to use the plists, it got an error:

```
Month 13 is out of bounds
```

I'm not sure what actually happened within UserEventAgent, but it's obvious that when it gets the error, it cannot deal with it and causes high CPU and RAM usage.

Comment: This doesn't work for me I tried almost three times but nothing happens.

Comment: @qwerty You still get the error despite having your date and time set before December 2017? Ideally, set Date and Time to Nov. 1, then kill the processes mentioned above with activity monitor.

Comment: I even tried that before. I also tried changing it to January 1 but it still doesn't work I think I should just ignore this error because I don't have high CPU usage or RAM usage. I hope apple fixes this in the next software update. Well at least this is better than the root bug:https://www.macrumors.com/how-to/temporarily-fix-macos-high-sierra-root-bug/

Comment: (I can’t add a comment, sorry.) I started getting the high CPU usage today because of UserEventAgent. It also uses a huge amount of RAM (30+ GB if I let it run long enough). Force quitting and rebooting changed nothing. I did a sample of the process and saw a ton of lines dealing with dates. When I changed the date to November my CPU usage went back to normal. The second I changed it to the present it went bonkers again. I wonder if this is related to the iOS date bug in 11.2.1? I hope Apple fixes it soon because my computer is unusable.

Comment: @qwerty Don't let your computer shut off at all until Apple patches this. I made the mistake of restarting when I first saw the error in my XCode console, and my RAM and CPU usage took a turn for the worse.. After some investigation I figured I'd do the above for a temporary solution, as my computer was almost useless. The error is mostly harmless unless you restart or try to load any plist files.

Comment: This does seem to work for me. Manually setting date to 11/3/17, save, force kill UserEvent agent (the one running under my username, not the one running as root), and the CPU and RAM stay stable. Re-enable automatic date and time, and it immediately starts spiking again.

Comment: I second @Ckacmaster’s advice: do *not* restart the computer.

Comment: Could you expand upon _”For some reason, the computer can't deal with this month and throws errors wherever there are databases or plists.”_ we have hundreds of computers where these month log entries are logged and not one is not working. Are you able to discern why some Mac and iOS devices have no issues when these messages are present? Also, I’m not saying you don’t have user agent issues, just not sure if correlation / causation / irrelevance to the month message from login window process.

Comment: @bmike Yes, December is the 12th month of the year, but Apple messed up, and somehow made the software think the 12th month is actually the 13th month of the year. Due to the month being a 13 which is not in the range of 1-12, any processes that have to use the date are broken. I haven't seen the month 13 bug on iOS, and have looked into the logs on iOS 11 devices, however some online are saying it applies to iOS also.. I do believe the loginwindow message is tied into the bug, I've seen it in the console on my machine. The UserEventAgent has the exact same error message.

Comment: @bmike From my observation I can tell you that if you see this message and do not restart your computer, no serious issues will occur. This is why some people have the message and do not have any serious problems with their computers. On restart, UserEventAgent and a lot of other processes have to load data from plist files and cannot do so. I don't know why the issue effects the plist files, but I do know that after I ran my application which involved plist files in Xcode, the console printed the Month 13 message and did not load any of the data within the plist file.

Comment: @Ckacmaster thanks for the details. We’re not seeing any breakage with many reboots, but I’m sure some are suffering. Just curious why we’re immune so far and knocks on wood of course...

Comment: Fixed as of Jan 1, 2018 (Luckily no month 14, back to 1) - Disappointed at Apple for letting such a massive error go on for an entire month. There is no excuse for the undue hardship this caused for so many Apple users. Unacceptable.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue with extremely high UserEventAgent CPU and memory usage starting at the beginning of December 2017. Console showed the "month out of bounds" error as described above.

I tried disk utility "first aid," reboots, safe mode (to clear system cache), clearing NVRAM and SMD, nothing helped. I did notice that the CPU and memory usage didn't spike in safe mode.

Like @tgray and [u/kidtexas](https://www.reddit.com/r/MacOS/comments/7hb0ke/bug_10131_usereventagent_100_cpu_use_and_30gb_ram/dqru8fy/), at some point I figured out that if I disabled all my custom launchd plists that the problem didn't occur.

I eventually wrote the little script below to help me debug which plist was causing the issue. It ended up being a plist that runs on the first of every month:

```
<key>StartCalendarInterval</key>
<dict>
    <key>Day</key>
    <integer>1</integer>
    <key>Hour</key>
    <integer>03</integer>
    <key>Minute</key>
    <integer>00</integer>
</dict>
```

*Many* of my plists use the `StartCalendarInterval` key, and using the script below I could show that they didn't seem to cause the spiking RAM and memory issues, so it's not entirely clear to me why one specific plist cause the problem. Regardless, this is how I sorted it out.

I *strongly* recommend readers look through the script to try to understand what it does instead of just copy and paste. Specifically, as written this will only work for plists in `~/Library/LaunchAgents` (not `/Library/LaunchDaemons` and others), and it intentionally only tests plists whose filename and `<key>Label</key>` follow the specific pattern: `com.USERNAME.my_plist_name[.plist]`. Before running it, I used a one-liner to `bootout` all of my plists: `for plist in com."$(whoami)".*.plist; do launchctl bootout gui/"${MYUID}"/"${plist%.plist}" || true; done`, and then verified they no longer appeared under `launchctl list` results.

```
#! /bin/bash
# https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/307512/month-13-is-out-of-bounds

set -euf -o pipefail

MYUID="$(id -u)"

pushd "${HOME}"/Library/LaunchAgents

while IFS= read -r -d '' plist; do
  echo "${plist}"
  stats=($(ps ux | grep -v grep | grep UserEventAgent | awk '{ print $3, $5}'))
  cpu="${stats[0]}"
  vmem="${stats[1]}"
  echo "CPU use and virtual memory size while disabled: ${stats[@]}"
  launchctl bootstrap gui/"${MYUID}" "${plist}"
  sleep 5
  stats=($(ps ux | grep -v grep | grep UserEventAgent | awk '{ print $3, $5}'))
  echo "CPU use and virtual memory size while enabled: ${stats[@]}"
  echo "Change in vmem: $(( "${vmem}" - "${stats[1]}" ))"
  echo
done < <(find . -iname "com.$(whoami).*.plist" -print0)

popd
```

Comment: Note to people running this: it assumes that all the agents it's testing are already disabled, so take heed to run the `bootout` (or similar) that n8henrie recommends.

Answer (score 1):

Like others, I was having high CPU usage and huge RAM usage from UserEventAgent (see my comment above).  Changing the date to November and force quitting UserEventAgent fixed things.  This all started on Saturday after I rebooted.

### Fix

I figured this out for me.  Hopefully for others with issues, this will work for you.

The issue was a LaunchAgent plist I have in ~/Library/LaunchAgents.  It's a simple plist file that calls StartCalendarInterval, which is a valid key for launchd plists.  The LaunchAgent job calls a shell script that copies some files to a backup location on the first day of the month.  The job is not being called at all - I think it is launchd checking the loaded jobs against the Calendar which is causing the issue.  As soon as I unloaded this plist and moved the file out of the directory, UserEventAgent was fine (after a force quit).   The second I loaded the plist (launchctl load xxxx), UserEventAgent went nuts.

StartCalendarInterval is a valid key for launchd as seen here in [Apple's docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/ScheduledJobs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000172i-CH1-SW2).

So for anyone having issues, check your LaunchAgent directories and looks for the StartCalendarInterval key (or any other calendar related key).  I did not have any issues with the time based interval plists.

**Note:** This doesn't fix the 'Month 13 out of bounds' errors, just the crazy UserEventAgent behavior.

Comment: Actually I don't have high User Event Agent CPU usage.And I also don't have high ZCPU and RAM usage.

Comment: This answer helped me. Though I didn't have problems with UserEventAgent but lsd went crazy. Luckily, I remember that I created plist with StartCalendarEvent by myself. Just disabled it and force-killed lsd.

Answer (score 0):

After reporting this to Apple and scaling the escalation chain, I was told this should be fixed in macOS 10.13.3.

Apparently, this is caused by an application [calling the Deprecated NSDate procedure ‘descriptionWithCalendarFormat’](https://robservatory.com/month-13-is-out-of-bounds/).

You can read more at https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/88417.

In some cases, editing or removing certain plist files will prevent programs from calling the deprecated procedure, but the real fix is an OS update.